# How to redirect all 404 errors page to home page / specified url in .htaccess?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, http-error-404

How to redirect 404 page to home page?

Comment: If my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Login to the admin and go to 
`System > Configuration > Web` and change the drop-down value for `CMS No Route Page` in the Default Pages section. You should be able to select your `Home Page`.

[image]

**Second method by .htaccess:**

For example, if you wish to redirect the 404 (File Not Found) errors to `http://example.com`, you should add this line to your .htaccess file:

> ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Or you can try like this way too,add the following code & replace YOURURL with the URL where you want the error 404 page redirected to.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://YOURURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
Note: If you have a specific 404 Url that you want to redirect to the homepage.
Here's how to redirect the target path should be "../"

**1. Catalog > Url Rewrite Management**

[image]

**2. Click Add URL Rewrite**

[image]

**3. Select Custom Url Rewrite**

[image]

**4.  Add your desired 404-page link in here.**

[image]

I hope this helps. Guys out there just correct me if I'm wrong. But I'm doing this one a lot in my regular tasks.

Comment: This will getting error

Comment: What do you mean @YKB?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting error message, when I was passing my Request url and Target url.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the error? Or what does the error says? And can you send me over the specific 404 page url from your site? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In 404 cms page, call `.phtml` file with this code. There will write a code like,

```
header(“HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found”);
header(“Location: /”);  // Redirect to home page
exit();
```